# Why doesn't Intellisense appear after typing Worksheets("Sheet1").?

Tags: vba, excel

I understand why it wouldn't pop up for ActiveSheet since it can return a worksheet or chart sheet so it wouldn't know which set of properties/methods to list, but if I'm explicitly referencing a worksheet within the Worksheets collection, why doesn't Intellisense get triggered?

I also want to extend this question to predefined constants. Sometimes a list of the predefined constants pops up for a property but sometimes it doesn't. Why is that? For example:

Application.Calculation=
will trigger a list of the predefined constants.

Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.Orientation=
will NOT trigger a list of predefined constants.

Thanks for your answers, folks! :)

Answer (score 3):

The Intellisense needs to know what is returned to give you the proper selection.

Have a look at the Object-Browser:

- `Application.Calulation` returns `XlCalculation`. You get the selection by Intellisense
- `Worksheets("Sheet1")` returns an unspecified `Object`, because it can be a `Worksheet`, but doesn't has to. That's why the Intellisense breaks at this level.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to VBA so I'm not sure how to check what object is returned by a property. So if I wanted to check what object Worksheets("Sheet1") returns, how is this done?  I understand the logic of your explanation, but how would referring to a specific worksheet be interpreted as anything but a worksheet? Thanks so much!

Comment: @GeekyFreaky You don't refer to a Worksheet, you refer to an item of the `Worksheets` collection, that can contain e.g charts too. To check if a `Worksheet`is returned, you can set it to a `Worksheet` object and check for error (raised if not)

Comment: Wait, isn't this the case for the Sheets collection? I understand that it you reference an item in the Sheets collection, then its ambiguous because you could be referencing a worksheet or a chart sheet. But if you're referencing an item in the Worksheets collection, you can only reference a worksheet - or am I wrong in that? Thanks so much for your reply!

Comment: @GeekyFreaky Even if  `Worksheets.Item` can only return a `Worksheet` it returns an unspecific `Object`  in Object-Browser (I don't know the reason, maybe a flaw), what leads to no IntelliSense.

Answer (score 2):

the Intellisense works if Excel know exactly what you want.

If you do this in your Sub or Function it works.

```
Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DUMMY")

sh.PageSetup.Orientation = here comes the Intellisense 

Set sh = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this one out. Again my confusion is why Worksheets("Sheet1") isn't specific enough??? It's a reference to a worksheet after all! How can it be interpreted as anything but?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare each object as a variable and clarify the kind of object to the program, Intellisense will work normally.

See examples below.
Intellisense does not work for Charts (1), Worksheets ("Sheet1"), Cells (1, 1).
But Ws, rng, myChart work.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myChart As Chart

    Set myChart = Charts(1)
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = Cells(1, 1)


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This raises another question - is it considered best practice to declare every object as a variable then?

Comment: @GeekyFreaky, If possible, declaring it as a variable makes coding easier.